# Auto refresh when data posted to server

Tags: javascript, php, push, page-refresh

I've been googling for the best part of 3 hours, maybe I'm not using the right keywords, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a php website (codeigniter) and I have a solid foundation in PHP, HTML and JS.

I have built and API which other websites post to and currently, a basic bootstrap php page which outputs the results. Currently I am (rather crudely) using an auto-refresh plugin on chrome to see the latest results (set to every 2 seconds).

But for my needs this is too slow.

Is there some service / platform that exists where when my API receives a post, it can push the change to my basic webpage without needing to manually refresh it?

Ideally, I need to get this down to less than 1 second, it is doing mission critical work :)

Thanks!

Comment: Look into websockets.

Comment: Thank you sir - this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh it periodically ( in example every one second):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

Maybe look at iframes if you don't want to refresh everything.